# JQuery $('#id") does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a noob in JQuery, trying my hands on the basic functionality of it

I have a html, like below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/start.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(mainFunction());
        $('#label1').prop('innerHTML', "test");
    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <label id="label1"></label>
</body>

</html>
```

From start.js, i'm trying to manipulate the elements in this html file like below.

```
function start(name){
    this.iam = name;
    this.getName = function(user){
        return this.iam;
    }
}

function mainFunction(){
    var label = $('#label1');
    var oStart = new start("test");
    label.prop("innerHTML" ,oStart.getName("test"));
}
```

When I try to lookup whats in the 'label' in the above code, i get [] printed on the console. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(mainFunction());` is your issue. Instead provide function reference to document.ready.

Like this:

```
$(mainFunction);
```

While doing `$(mainFunction());` you are invoking the function `mainFunction` while setting up the handler, which means it gets executed too early before the DOM tree has been constructed.

Or in order to avoid confusion you could do:

```
$(function(){
   mainFunction();
});
```

Also remember that this issue will not happen if you move your script just before the end of the body tag. You do not have to listen to document ready handler. Plus as a shorthand you could just do `label.html(oStart.getName("test"));`

Comment: Thanks. that was simple.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait for the DOM to be ready before using jQuery.

This is done this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // All your code touching the DOM in here
});
```

Also note that this line: `$(mainFunction());` uses the return value of `mainFunction`, it does not trigger it when DOM is ready.